# SimpleTabBarController Leaks Memory

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to debug a memory leak in fairly complex TabBarController app on rotation. So I created a very simple skeleton app with an AppDelegate, FirstViewController and SecondViewController each connected to separate nib with a view and a label as instructed in iOS Programming, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 2nd Ed. The tab works and the views display. When I enable rotation I STILL get a leak on an iPad device on rotations as:

CALayer UIKit UIView _createLayerWithFrame
UIImageView UIClassicController _setupWindow

EDIT:  Well FWIW. I used the Xcode 3.26 and iOS4.3 templates:

View --> iPad --> NO CODE ADDED --> test on iPad2 NO LEAKS on rotation with this template code:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

View --> iPhone --> ADD SAME EXACT CODE AS ABOVE TO PROJECT --> test on iPad2 SAME LEAKS
View --> iPhone --> ADD Slightly different code --> test on iPad2 SAME LEAKS

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x {
     //return YES;
     return (x== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(x);
 }
```

So I am going to wait and see if I get a leak when testing against an iPhone4. This is a very reproducible error requiring the addition of one line of code. Confused.

Answer (score -2):

After `[tbController setViewControllers:viewControllers];` you need to release the array `viewControllers` with `[viewControllers release];`.

Comment: You are not right. View viewControllers is autoreleased object. Keep looking into the code.

Comment: The words he uses for his code is misleading. viewControllers is an array, not a view. He says: 
NSArray *viewControllers= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,nil];

Comment: Ahh my bad, it looks like his array *is* autoreleased.